# Storyboard - Pop to Root UIViewController Without UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a `UIViewController` hierarchy that consists of a Root View Controller, which segues to a `UITabBarController` which has several `UIViewControllers` under it.  Each of those tab `UIViewControllers` has its own `UINavigationController`.  There is no shared `UINavigationController`, and none applying to the Root View Controller.  Now I have a situation in which I need to pop all the way back to the Root View Controller from one of the tab `UIViewControllers`.  However, since the Root View Controller and the tab `UIViewControllers` do not share a common `UINavigationController`, I am unable to simply call `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]`.  Is it possible to pop to the Root View Controller (or unwind my Segues back to the root programmatically) without a shared, common `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Is what you call "Root View Controller" a navigation controller?  Or is it contained by one as its root?  Is the tab bar vc pushed or presented?

Comment: No, the Root View Controller is not a UINavigationController.  It's a standard UIViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once, try this

```
UIStoryboard *storyBrd = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *controller = nil;
controller = [storyBrd instantiateInitialViewController];
self.view.window.rootViewController = controller;
```

This initial view controller is your RootViewController. Else you can also use the method

```
[storyBrd instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:<View Controller's Restoration ID>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understand the vc arrangement:

```
                             |-navvc
                             |   |--rootvc-(pushes)-stack...
"root" vc-(presents)->tabvc--|    
                             |-navvc
                                 |--rootvc-(pushes)-stack...
```

Its easy to unwind all of this so long as you're holding the handles to the right stuff.  The navigation vcs within the tabs can be accessed by any view controller on their stacks with `self.navigationController`.

You'll need to have ahold on either the tab bar vc or the one you call "root" vc, also.  You can arrange that with a property on your app delegate.

The only other tricky thing to remember is that the transition from the "root" vc to the tab bar is a present, not a push, so it must be undone with a dismiss, not a pop.  To express this in code, lets say you've got a handle to the tab bar vc on your app delegate....

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarVC;

- (void)popEverything:(BOOL)animated;

@end

// AppDelegate.m

// get the tab bars tabs (which are presumed to be navigation vcs)
// dismiss the tab bar vc (which was presumed to be presented)
// iterate the navigation vcs, popping all of them to root
- (void)popEverything:(BOOL)animated {
    NSArray *viewControllers = self.tabBarVC.viewControllers;
    [self.tabBarVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:^{
        for (UINavigationController *navVC in viewControllers) {
            [navVC popToRootViewControllerAnimated:animated];
        }
    }];
}
```

Caveats apply: still guessing a little about your vc arrangement, and haven't tested the foregoing.